# How can I clone a Github repo that requires a password in Google Collaboratory?

Tags: git, github, google-colaboratory

I want to clone a private repo onto the colabs VM, but there is no way to input the username and password. Is there a one liner where you can pass the username and password along with the clone command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
!git clone https://username:password@remote
```

if your username contains a `@` use instead `%40`

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using `%40`, there was a special character in my username that was causing issues